# Subtlety in Correspondence Theorem for Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have something of a subtle question about the correspondence theorem for rings.  The theorem is typically stated like this: 
Let $A$ be a ring, and $I$ an ideal of $A$.  There is a $1-1$, order-preserving correspondence between
\begin{align*}
\{\mbox{Ideals}\  J\ ,\  I\subseteq J \subseteq A\} &\leftrightarrow  \{\mbox{Ideals}\  \bar{J}\subseteq A/I \} \\
\end{align*}
I just finished reading a direct proof which constructed the forward direction, and inverse maps for the $1-1$ correspondence.  For the forward direction, we consider the canonical epimorphism $\varphi : A \rightarrow A/I$ sending $a \mapsto a+ I$, and restrict to $J$.  That is we consider the map 
$$\varphi |_{J} : J \rightarrow A/I $$
The proof proceeds to establish that $\mbox{ker}(\varphi |_{J}) = I$.  For this step it matters that $I \subset J$, because otherwise we might have 
$$ \mbox{ker}(\varphi |_{J}) = I \cap J \ne I $$
The isomorphism theorem for rings tells us that 
$$ \mbox{Im}(\varphi |_{J}) \cong J / \mbox{ker}(\varphi |_{J}) = J/I$$
Then the argument concludes that because $J/I$ is an ideal of $A/I$, the image does in fact ''land'' in the correct set.
 Basically I'm wondering where exactly it is necessary that $I \subseteq J$.  It seems that the above argument could be sidestepped.  Isn't it clear by the definitions (and isn't it true even if $I \nsubseteq J$) that $\mbox{Im}(\varphi |_{J}) = J/I$?  I'm surely missing some detail.  Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: If we don't have $I\subseteq J$, then $J$ won't consist of cosets of $I$, and $J/I$ begins to look very suspicious. What would it be?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say "then $J$ won't consist of cosets of $I$."  $J$ is an ideal of $A$   in a coset free world.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear. What I meant to say was: $J$ is not a union of cosets of $I$, so what would the elements of $J/I$ be? After all $J/I$ should be a quotient group (in addition to being an ideal of $A/I$). And to that end it is already necessary that $I$ is a subgroup of $J$. Hence $I$ should be a subset of $J$.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the projection map sends *all* ideals of $R$ to ideals of $R/I$. This is surjective, but not generally an injective map - two different ideals of $R$ can be sent to the same ideal of $R/I$. And when you go back by taking an ideal of $R/I$ and unioning the cosets of $I$ it contains to get an ideal of $R$ you will wind up with an ideal that contains $I$, so the inverse map takes ideals of $R/I$ and returns ideals of $R$ containing $I$.